# stripping when selecting

Tags: mysql, matching, stripping

1. I have two tables, ones lists `students_playing` but it's about 10 characters long, first and last name combined....
2. I want to select from the `avail_students` but I don't want to select the students that has the same name that matches the first 5 characters.

My select command right now is:

```
select * from avail_students where lastplayed<now() and name not IN strip(students_playing),5)
```

I know the last part is not correct but I don't even know where to start.

Any kind of help I get from this is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is the problem is related to the title of the post?

Comment: Also I don't any `strip()` method in MySQL. You are probably looking for `substring()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring. And `IN()` expects a list, not a string.

Comment: hi, thank you for pointing out my title

The issue I have here is that I have about 50 rows in the `students_playing` table... i don't know how to match/include all of them to filter in my select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [LEFT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) and [nested subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) are what you are looking for.

The example below should compare the first 5 characters only.

```
SELECT * FROM avail_students 
WHERE lastplayed < now() 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM students_playing
    WHERE LEFT( students_playing.name, 5 ) = LEFT( avail_students.name, 5 )
)
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! I had no idea this was even possible with a one liner query! Thank you so much! You have made my day!